# Japanese Law: Do I need to get permissions and pay fees to create 3D models of ancient Japanese temples?

Tags: copyright, japan, cultural-heritage

I want to create 3D models of Japanese ancient temples such as the "**Fujiyoshida, Japan at Chureito Pagoda and Mt. Fuji**" for my commercial mobile app.

Here is the link to this temple: https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/fujiyoshida-japan-chureito-pagoda-mt-fuji-625757552

So, I have 3 simple questions:

1. Who owns the copyright of ancient Japanese temples ?
2. Do I need to get permissions and pay fees to create 3D models of
   ancient Japanese temples ?
3. If I don't create exactly identical 3D models of these temples, but I only
   create a 3D model of a **generalized or stylized** ancient Japanese temple, do I
   still need to be concerned about the copyright and permissions ?

---

**Some more notes:**

I am in the US.

I am not familiar with the copyright law in Japan regarding these ancient temples.

The reason I ask this question is that some countries may have special provisions regarding their own cultural heritages. For example, Italy has the following provision regarding their own cultural heritages:

**The Italian Cultural Heritage Code**

**The Italian Cultural Heritage Code (Legislative Decree No. 42 of January 22, 2004) states that faithful digital reproductions of cultural heritage can only be used for commercial purposes after receiving authorisation from the cultural heritage institution that kept the physical work, and after payment of a fee.**

You can get more info about this if you google "**Italy the decree law d.lgs. 42/2004**".  Thanks to user @NicolaSap for this info.

Comment: Note that use of the term "copyright" in inapt and may cause confusion. The kind of rights created in the Italian Cultural Heritage Code are not called "copyrights."

Answer (score 2):

### No one

Ancient Japanese temples are not protected by copyright. And neither are Italian cultural heritage items.

That does not answer whether you need to pay fees. For example, the Italian law requires you to get authorisation, but that has nothing to do with copyright law. I don’t know if there is an equivalent Japanese law.